# Preventing loops when changing parent of a node in the adjacency list model of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, adjacency-list, adjacency-list-model

[image]

I want the user to be able to change the parent of a node. However, there has to be some check so that the loop situation does not arise. For eg. Parent of 9 is 8. Parent of 8 is 7. User might assign the parent of 7 as 9. In this situtation the tree will be in a never ending loop.

I have thought of a simple solution which is that while changing the parent I will check in PHP, if the new parent node id < child node id.

However, I have a intuition that there might be some situation in which this check will fail and There will be some loops created by the user.

Is there a simple solution to change the parent of a node while making sure that there is no situation of loop formation.

Comment: If you have MYSQL 8.x you could use a recursive CTE to check if the new parent is a descendant.

Comment: I am sure there must be a simple solution.

Comment: Take a look here for an extensive discussion of using MYSQL for hierarchical data (it predates recursive CTE): https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Is my solution incorrect? Just checking whether the child node id should be greater than parent node id. Will this prevent loops?

Comment: It will prevent loops but it will also prevent many non-loops. E.g. if you try to change the parent of Cameras (6) to Other Smartphones (11) it will be blocked even though there's no loop.

Comment: Sir, even if it prevents non loops then not a problem. Loops should be prevented, even if it has the side effect of blocking non loops. 
The problem is that I have a gut feeling that my solution is not correct. I am having a gut feeling that my simple solution has some flaw and there will still be loops.

Comment: The problem is that it's likely to block almost all moves. Pretty much anything left-to-right in your diagram will be blocked.

Comment: Sir, the priority is to prevent loops at any cost. If the user is not able to move the node, then he should create new node as a child with same contents as the node that can't be moved. 
However, there should never be loop. Even it has side effects.
I have a feeling somehow, that my simple solution is not full proof. There will be some loops even if I compare that child node id is greater than parent node id.

Comment: Why even bother allowing moves then?

Comment: Sir, because client is requesting the feature. Also we have to prevent the loops. If there is a side effect of not allowing few transfers then we can inform to the client that this has been done to prevent the loops.